# windows powershell open website and login exits with NULL-VALUED

Tags: windows, powershell, authentication, null

I want to login to a website with powershell commands in windows with following code:

```
    $username = "hansmueller@test.com" 
    $password = "test_21" 

    $ie = New-Object -ComObject 'internetExplorer.Application'
    $ie.Visible= $true

    $ie.Navigate("http://testsite.test")

    While ($ie.Busy -eq $true) {Start-Sleep -Seconds 3;}

    $usernamefield = $ie.document.getElementById('name')
    $usernamefield.value = $username

    $passwordfield = $ie.document.getElementById('pw')
    $passwordfield.value = $password
```

It opens the website but doesnt login and gives me the error:

```
You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At line:1 char:1
+ $ie.Document.getElementById("name").value = $username;$ie.D ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull

You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At line:1 char:65
+ ... = $username;$ie.Document.getElementById("pw").value=$pass ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
```

Comment: It looks like `$ie.document.getElementById('name')` doesn't exist i.e. there is no `name` element. Have you verified it does before you tried to assign it?

Comment: The error says at line1 char1 that would be $ie .. the element it name exists.